# Which is correct: "I would rather not" or "I would rather not to"?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if I need to include *to* in the following context?

> Person A: How about you tell me how you managed to ruin my shirt?
>
> Person B: I would rather not (**to**).

Is the use of *to* optional there?

Comment: The use of *to* is prohibited here - because "I would rather not" is followed (when something follows it at all) by the bare infinitive - as in Kate Bunting's square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of 'to' is not required in this context.

*I would rather not [tell you].*

Comment: As far as I know, it is not even used by people. Not eve optionally.